# How to center a TextView and resize its content to fill a whole *any*Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently using the following layout sketch to make my application layout:

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout HORIZONTAL orientation>
      <Programmed LinearLayout VERTICAL orientation>
        <Programmed ImageView/>
        <*ANY*Layout>
          <Programmed AutoResizeTextView/>
        <*ANY*Layout/>
      <LinearLayout/>
      <Programmed View as Separator/>
    <LinearLayout/>
    (Repeats till screen heigth complete)
  <LinearLayout/>
<ScrollView/>
```

The above layout results in the following result:

[image: listView]

As you can see the text is small and right next to the image, I want the text in the center of the View and resized to fit the whole space.

The thing is, I don't know if there is somethin in my code intentionally denying me to center the text but I have tried all of these options and didn't work:

```
TextView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER (tried CENTER_HORIZONTAL also)
*ANY*Layout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER (also CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
RelativeLayoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

So here is my code for the textView, if there is any problem with it making me unable to center it please let me know:

```
RelativeLayout lb = new RelativeLayout(this);
AutoResizeTextView tv = new AutoResizeTextView(this);
//Fix for android 4.0.4 versions and earlier
final String DOUBLE_BYTE_SPACE = "\u3000";
String fixString = "";
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1
        && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
    fixString = DOUBLE_BYTE_SPACE;
}
tv.setText(fixString + "The text" + fixString);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lptv = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lptv.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,iv.getId());
//End of Fix
lb.setLayoutParams(lptv);
tv.setText(name);
la.addView(lb);
lb.addView(tv);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
layout.addView(la);
```

So that I'm clear with the result expected, here is a picture sketching the expected result:
[image: eXPECTEDresult]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: r u creating custom listview using xml or programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to put horizontal `LinearLayout` rows inside a vertical `LinearLayout`. To make the `TextView`s stretch horizontally you can give them a `width` of 0 and a `weight` of 1.

To make them stretch vertically you can make the `ImageView` and `LinearLayout` `wrap_content` and the `TextView` `match_parent`. Or set a fixed size.

Once you get the `TextView` to occupy all the space (you can test this by giving it a background color), you can use a library such as [AutoFitTextView](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView) to make the text expand to fill that space.

For better performance, consider using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) instead of your `ScrollView` with vertical `LinearLayout` combo.

Comment: Thanks! I used http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html and got it done with ListView